# json.parse of valid JSON string returns another string

Tags: javascript, json

I am running `json.parse` and getting back the following as a string - why doesn't it convert it into a JSON object?

```
{"fields": [{"MDID" : "text", "length":"20"},{"Email Address" : "Email", "length":"255"},{"Secondary Email" : "Email", "length":"255"},{"First Name" : "text", "length":"255"},{"Last Name" : "text", "length":"255"},{"Age" : "text", "length":"8"},{"Date of Birth" : "date"},{"Phone" : "phone", "length":"20"}],"primaryKey": ["Email Address"],"required": ["MDID"]}
```

The variable being passed in also has a `typeof` string too. So, I am not sure why it took the string and still gave me back a string.

Everything I am reading says it should give me back a JSON object.

Comment: Please give us the code you are using. The example JSON object is already a valid object, and does not need to be parsed.

Comment: How are you getting this variable?  How are you trying to parse it?  There may be an issue in your code.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON object".  JSON is a *string*.  Once it's parsed, then it's an object.

Comment: is the input possibly double stringified?

Comment: @dandavis: Yes, you can use objects in a JSON data string, but the term "JSON object" isn't a thing.  Would you refer to a number inside an XML file as an "XML number"?

Comment: hmm re-reading, i will agree that the usage of the term by OP is incorrect (it should be converted to a JS Object by JSON.parse), but as used by tcooc in the first comment, it's fine.

Comment: I am using Express, EJS, and jquery on the front end. I am using multer to upload a file, both a json and an excel file to analyze the data inside them. I am then taking the excel file and creating a string from the data. Then I take that data string and parse with JSON.parse. It works on the JSON file, but does not work on the Excel file using ExcelJS. I didn't show code because there is just so much code being used here, and I wanted to keep it general to identify possible problems. If I can isolate further, I will post code. Thanks Rocket for the terminology, but I need a parsed object.

Comment: @dandavis - put your answer in, I will vote it up. That was the problem. When I called JSON.parse a second time it worked.